# Python: Collect all xlsx. - Open - Add Column - Save in new folder

Tags: python, excel

I am new with Python but trying to write a code which add a column on multiple .xlsx files and saves this files with the origin name to a new folder.

I have started with some coding beneath, but missing some code in open all files and saving to my `DestPath`. Would be pleased if any has a solution for this:

```
from os import listdir, path
import pandas as pd
import xlrd



SourcePath = 'C:\' #Source Path
DestPath = 'C:\' #Destination Path


# Listing up all .xlsx files from Source
def find_xlsx_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".xlsx" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]

filenames = find_xlsx_filenames(SourcePath)
fname = path.join(SourcePath, filenames[0]) # Tar første fil i mappa.

outname = path.join(outputdata, filenames[0])


for i in range(len(filenames)):
    fname = path.join(SourcePath, filenames[i])

df = pd.read_excel(fname) #Read Excel file as a DataFrame

df['new_col'] = 'Sort Data' #Adding a new column named <Sort Data>


#To save it back as Excel
df.to_excel(DestPath, outname) #Write DateFrame back as Excel file
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this works

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:/'

for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfile = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx')]

for xlsf in xlsfile:
    df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(roots, xlsf))
    df['Sort Data'] = ' '
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(roots, xlsf), index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks for proposal. The code runs (just had to add r because of a unicode error.  -   r'C:/'

The code seems to not find or cant open my xlsx files since there is no  change in the files after code is ran. Will I maybe need to specify which Column to add 'Sort Data' in? Let say I already have fields with data from A-H and Sort Data should be header for 'I'.

Comment: It does work in my system. I hope you have `.xlsx` file in the  directory you are searching. By default, 'Sort Data' column will be added as the last column. Would be good if you can provide any screenshot of the file in the C directory

Are you making any other change in the code or would like to see the directory

Comment: Rajat, please find "Screen" in my original post.

Comment: It should ideally work. Try to print `xlsfile` and see if you get excel files. I believe extension of the excel files are `.xlsx` not `.xls`

Comment: You are correct, Rajat. Created som sample files as you may have done and it seems to work. It does tho add a blank column in 'A', moving the rest 1 column to the right and adds 'Sort data' as last.

It seems like there is something tricky with my actual files that may has something to do with the rights of the files. See screen 2.

Comment: Seems like you do not have authority to the modify in the directory

Comment: You are correct again, Rajat :)

See screen 3. Seems to work,  but as I said last post the row 1 seems to move one right with the code. Do you have any suggestions for solving this? As you see, Orders should stay in Column 'A'

Comment: use `df.to_excel(os.path.join(roots, xlsf), index = False)`

Comment: If I just quickly opened every single file and saved one by one (CTLR +S) and closed them afterwards it worked. Dunno why, but now its done. Case closed.